# PHP form option fields will not display current value from file

Tags: php, forms, sed, exec

I've been working on a PHP form that changes values in a file on my server. The form changes the values correctly but I need the `<option value="round" <?php if($shape == 'round'){?>selected="selected"<?php }?>>Round</option>` part of the form to always show to current value that is set in the file, currently it does not.

```
#file contents (the lines the values are on changed on a regular basis)
size=large
color-name=red
shape=round
height=short
weight=heavy

<?php

$file = "/home/user/color.props";
$contents = file($file, FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

foreach($contents as $line) {
    list($option, $value) = explode('=', $line);
    if ($option == 'color-name') {
        $color_name = $value;
    } elseif ($option == 'shape') {
        $shape = $value;
    }
}

    if(isset($_REQUEST['color_choice'])){
        exec('sed -i '.escapeshellarg('s/color-name=.*/color-name='.$_REQUEST['color_choice'].'/g')." /home/user/color.props");
        echo 'Color setting has been updated';
    }

?>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <select name="color_choice">;
        <option value="round" <?php if($shape == 'round'){?>selected="selected"<?php }?>>Round</option>;
        <option value="square" <?php if($shape == 'square'){?>selected="selected"<?php }?>>Square</option>;
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Can you also paste the contents of your file?

Comment: Done. I was using: $color_name = explode("=", trim($contents[2])); but the lines the values are on in the file is always changing so it wasn't working very well.

Comment: You're accessing `$color_name` like an array but based on your code I don't think it will ever contain more than one value, thus, `$color_name[1]` will always be null...

Answer (score 0):

I'm still unclear on what exactly you're trying to accomplish. Your current code is only saving the last `'color-name'` and `'shape'` objects being read in from the file. It then can configure the `selected` option by making this change:

```
<option value="red" <?php if($color_name == 'red'){?>selected="selected"<?php }?>>Red</option>;
<option value="blue" <?php if($color_name == 'blue'){?>selected="selected"<?php }?>>Blue</option>;
<option value="green" <?php if($color_name == 'green'){?>selected="selected"<?php }?>>Green</option>;
<option value="purple" <?php if($color_name == 'purple'){?>selected="selected"<?php }?>>Purple</option>;
```

NOTE: The way you're reading in the file appends carriage returns/line returns at the end of your variables...for example, `$color_name` on my end contains two extra hex values at the end of the string: `x0d` and `x0a`

EDIT #2: Try making your form like this:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <select id="color_choice">
        <option id="round">Round</option>
        <option id="square">Square</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
<script>
    var option = document.getElementById("color_choice");
    option.options['<?php echo $shape ?>'].selected = true;
</script>
```

I'm pretty sure this will work, changes I made were: 
1) Using javascript instead of php to change selected 
2) Using `id` attributes instead of `value` or `name` 
3) Added `<script>` tag at the end of form (it may not work if it's before)

You'll have to make changes to the form and the script depending on what type of values you're pulling from the file...but you should be able to figure out how to handle that.

Comment: I will try to clarify what I am trying to accomplish: The form edits the value in the color.props value, this works perfectly. I want the option value field to always reflect the actual (current) value in the color.props file. If I change it to "blue" the option value field on the form should say "blue". Currently the form field option just resets to the first value "red" no matter what the value is in the color.props file.

Comment: @jcrane Try running this line again after the file changes: `$contents = file($file, FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);`

Comment: To be safe, place it after any line of code that makes changes to the file.

Comment: I gave that a try and the form field still doesn't reflect the value in the file.

Comment: @jcrane Please see my NOTE in my post. `$color_name` contains carriage returns at the end of the value. Please use [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) to trim the last two characters off of `$color_name` and see if that helps. If you want to double check the exact values contained in the variable, call `echo bin2hex($color_name)`. It will print hex values of the characters, which you can cross-reference with [this chart](http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif)

Comment: I tried $test = mb_substr($color_name, 0, -2); and echo $test doesn't display anything.

Comment: Try `$test = mb_substr($color_name,0,strlen($color_name)-2)`. If mb_substr() isn't working, the regular `substr()` method may work.

Comment: Just gave that a try and no luck either. I've updated my original question to try and phrase it better. I also am using shape as the example instead of the color value as I'm assuming that is where the hex values were coming from.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to take a bit of a break from this project but I'll try that over the next few days and if it works I'll mark your answer as resolved. If not I'll start from scratch and start a new topic.